# Capistrano initial deployment failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, vps

I have trouble while deploying Rails 3 project with Capistrno to the linode VDS. Error looks like:

```
lifecoder@lifecoder-VirtualBox:~/projects/ruby/avtolife$ cap deploy:update
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:lifecoder/avtolife.git master"
    command finished in 2964ms
  * executing "if [ -d /srv/avtolife/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /srv/avtolife/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard aec5c7f44151ca74d8eb384c478d6707719ee680 && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q git@bitbucket.org:lifecoder/avtolife.git /srv/avtolife/shared/cached-copy && cd /srv/avtolife/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy aec5c7f44151ca74d8eb384c478d6707719ee680; fi"
    servers: ["original-parts.net"]
    [lifecoder@original-parts.net] executing command
 ** [original-parts.net :: err] Host key verification failed.
 ** [original-parts.net :: err] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
    command finished in 1401ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /srv/avtolife/releases/20120620203352; true"
    servers: ["original-parts.net"]
    [lifecoder@original-parts.net] executing command
    command finished in 588ms
    failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.2' -c 'if [ -d /srv/avtolife/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /srv/avtolife/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard aec5c7f44151ca74d8eb384c478d6707719ee680 && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q git@bitbucket.org:lifecoder/avtolife.git /srv/avtolife/shared/cached-copy && cd /srv/avtolife/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy aec5c7f44151ca74d8eb384c478d6707719ee680; fi'" on lifecoder@original-parts.net
```

I need an idea on how to trace where the particular error is done. I'm pretty new in *nix and rails so some parts of config looks like magic for me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When something go wrong with Capistrano deployment - run scenario commands one by one on the remote server. My trouble was with the target server - local Ubuntu asked for remote IP address acceptance and die when have no answer from cap script. After acceptance same script runs fine.